# django file upload issue

Tags: python, django, templates, django-file-upload

> I have tried to upload a picture using Django file field

> and in my **models.py** file

```
class Students(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    admin = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    profile_picture = models.FileField()
    objects = models.Manager()
```

> and in project's **urls.py** file

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('student_management_app.urls')),
]+static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)+static(settings.STATIC_URL,document_root=settings.STATIC_FILE_ROOT)
```

> in my **setting.py** file I have specified the directories like this

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_FILE_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
```

> and in the **template page** I tried to view the image that got uploaded to the **media folder**

```
<tbody>
                    {% for student in students %}
                    <tr>
                      <td>{{ student.admin.id }}</td>
                      <td><img src ="{{ student.profile_picture }}" style="width: 100px"></td>
                      <td>{{ student.admin.first_name }}</td>
                      <td>{{ student.admin.last_name }}</td>
                      <td>{{ student.gender }}</td>
                      <td>{{ student.address }}</td>
                      <td>{{ student.admin.email }}</td>
                      <td>{{ student.course_id.course_name}}</td>
                      <td>{{ student.session_start_year }}</td>
                      <td>{{ student.session_end_year }}</td>
                      <td>{{ student.admin.date_joined }}</td>
                      <td>{{ student.admin.last_login }}</td>
                      <td><a href="/EditStudent/{{ student.admin.id }}" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a></td>
                      <td><a href="/DeleteStudent/{{ student.admin.id }}" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a></td>
                    </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                  </tbody>
```

> the image is getting uploaded perfectly but I am not being able to serve them. [right now the template looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vi3S.jpg)view them in the template
> the traceback is showing

```
11/Sep/2021 18:32:30] "GET /media/010040.jpg HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[11/Sep/2021 18:32:30] "GET /media/1580467939054_Anitha.jpg HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[11/Sep/2021 18:32:30] "GET /media/1580467939054_Anitha_mM61nlO.jpg HTTP/1.1" 302 0
```

**

> app urls.py

**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.urls import path
from . import views, AdminViews, StaffViews, StudentViews



urlpatterns = [
    
    path('demo', views.demo, name='demo'),
    path('DoLogin', views.DoLogin, name='DoLogin'),
    path('LoginPage', views.LoginPage, name='LoginPage'),
    path('GetUserDetails', views.GetUserDetails, name='GetUserDetails'),
    path('LogoutUser', views.LogoutUser, name='LogoutUser'),
    path('admin_home', views.admin_home, name='admin_home'),
    path('AddStaff', views.AddStaff, name='AddStaff'),
    path('AddStaffSave', views.AddStaffSave, name='AddStaffSave'),
    path('AddCourse', views.AddCourse, name ='AddCourse'),
    path('AddCourseSave', views.AddCourseSave, name='AddCourseSave'),
    path('AddSubject', views.AddSubject, name ='AddSubject'),
    path('AddSubjectSave', views.AddSubjectSave, name='AddSubjectSave'),
    path('AddStudent', views.AddStudent, name='AddStudent'),
    path('AddStudentSave', views.AddStudentSave, name='AddStudentSave'),
    path('ManageStaff', views.ManageStaff, name='ManageStaff'),
    path('ManageStudent', views.ManageStudent, name='ManageStudent'),
    path('ManageCourse', views.ManageCourse, name='ManageCourse'),
    path('ManageSubject', views.ManageSubject, name='ManageSubject'),
    path('EditStaff/<str:staff_id>', views.EditStaff, name='EditStaff'),
    path('EditStaffSave', views.EditStaffSave, name='EditStaffSave'),
    path('EditStudent/<str:student_id>', views.EditStudent, name='EditStudent'),
    path('EditStudentSave', views.EditStudentSave, name='EditStudentSave'),
    path('EditCourse/<str:course_id>', views.EditCourse, name='EditCourse'),
    path('EditCourseSave', views.EditCourseSave, name='EditCourseSave'),
    path('EditSubject/<str:subject_id>', views.EditSubject, name='EditSubject'),
    path('EditSubjectSave', views.EditSubjectSave, name='EditSubjectSave'),
    path('DeleteStaff/<str:staff_id>', views.DeleteStaff, name='DeleteStaff'),
    path('DeleteStudent/<str:student_id>', views.DeleteStudent, name='DeleteStudent'),
    path('DeleteCourse/<str:course_id>', views.DeleteCourse, name='DeleteCourse'),
    path('DeleteSubject/<str:subject_id>', views.DeleteSubject, name='DeleteSubject'),
    path('StaffHome', views.StaffHome, name='StaffHome'),
    path('StudentHome', views.StudentHome, name='StudentHome'),
]
```

> when I inspected the template code in sources the image link is
> showing as
> **the path is showing two media  is this the problem**

```
`<td><img src ="/media/media/1580467939054_Anitha_wjltRgu.jpg" style="width: 100px"></td>`
```

**can anyone help me???**

Comment: are you sure that the image was uploaded to the `media` folder? if not then show code of view used in creation and form tag

Answer (score 0):

You should work with the `.url` of the image, so:

```
<img src="{{ student.profile_picture.url }}">
```

In your template you edit/remove items with what looks like a GET request, in order to edit data, a POST, PUT, or PATCH request should be used, and removing a data entry should be done with a POST or DELETE request.

Comment: @vishnuchandran: can you share the urls of the `student_management_app`, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69143413/edit) the question?

Comment: when i inspected the template code in sources the image link is showing as    <td><img src ="/media/media/1580467939054_Anitha_wjltRgu.jpg" style="width: 100px"></td> the path is showing two media  is this the problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<td><img src ="{{ student.profile_picture.url }}" style="width: 100px"></td>
```

Comment: can you share your file structure? where you put the image?

Answer (score 0):

**There are many problems with your code**:
**1**-In your model, use the field for image uploadig ImageField ( to use ImageField you need to have installed [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) ):

```
profile_picture=models.ImageField(upload_to="images", null=True, blank=True)
```

**2**-you must use a form with following attributes:

```
 enctype="multipart/form-data"
   method="post"
```

**Note**:
in [shell](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/django-admin/#shell) django we have following:

assume `upload_to='images'`:

```
\>\>\>student.profile_picture
<ImageFieldFile: images/cat.jpg>

\>\>\>student.profile_picture.url
'http://yourDomain/media/images/cat.jpg'

\>\>\>student.profile_picture.path
'media/images/cat.jpg'

\>\>\>student.profile_picture.name
'images/cat.jpg'
```

**also** see following links:
[Files in models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/files/#using-files-in-models)
[Serving files uploaded](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development)
[Configuring settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#media-root)